# Chromecast discover with multiple Activities and CCL

Tags: google-cast

I'm developing an Android app for Chromecast which makes use of the Chromecast Companion Library (CCL) together with a MediaRouterButton. When the first activity is created, onCastDeviceDetected is called and MediaRouterButton is set to visible. The second activity is created from within the first activity, but no onCastDeviceDetected is called in the second activity!
What is best practice for keeping state of discovered Chromecast devices with the combination of multiple activities, MediaRouterButton and CCL?

In CCL version 1.8 onCastDeviceDetected was always called when starting a new activity, so this issue seems to be introduced (with purpose) in version 1.9 ?

Comment: Could you show how you are using the CCL and the MediaRouterButton, please? Adding your code will significantly increase your chances of a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if what you are asking was ever working differently; I looked at the code and there hasn't been any changes in the behavior around that but I could be wrong.

Right now  CCL doesn't provide an API for you to do that. From CCL's point of view, availability of routes hasn't changed when you move from one activity to another so it doesn't fire that callback (and the intention was not to do that either). The problem you are facing can be addressed by either of these:

- Keep track of the route availability in, say, your Application instance; register a VideoCastConsumer in your Application class and listen to onCastAvailabilityChanged(). Keep the result in your Application instance and then when you start a new activity, ask your application instance if there is any cast device or not (based on the preserved value that I talked about); that would give the initial state. Have your activity register a consumer with the same callback so from that point on, the activity is self-contained as long as it is alive.
- File a feature request for CCL so I add an API to get you around the need to add that piece in your own application instance.

Comment: Has CCL API been updated  or is there a plan to update it to include this functionality now?

Comment: Yes; a while ago a new API was made available to tell you if there is any route available or not: VideoCastManager. isAnyRouteAvailable() so basically, in any activity, you need to do two things: (1) Register the callback onCastAvailabilityChanged(boolean castPresent) as was described earlier, and also call this new API to set the current state. The  new API syncs you up immediately and the callback will help you stay in sync throughout the lifecycle of the activity